# How to mount a local folder using docker image for Jupyter notebook?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I use docker image below:
https://hub.docker.com/r/gw000/keras-full

It works great; however, I want to mount a local folder so I can save and use local notebook files. I use command below:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v c:/Jupyter:/srv gw000/keras-full
```

The command runs successfully; however, I cannot create a new notebook because I get an error message below:

> Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb

I've tried the following:

- I've given "FULL" access permission to Jupter folder("everyone" user)
- I've tried command from the first submitted answer
- I've  tried Firefox and Edge browsers using normal and admin modes

Docker image requires password "keras" as per example below:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/srv gw000/keras-full
```

I'm not able to figure out how to use mapping folder and password at the same time.

My Environment:

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker Desktop

Docker logs:

```
[I 10:35:10.240 NotebookApp] Writing notebook server cookie secret to /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/notebook_cookie_secret
[W 10:35:10.844 NotebookApp] WARNING: The notebook server is listening on all IP addresses and not using encryption. This is not recommended.
[I 10:35:13.007 NotebookApp] jupyter_tensorboard extension loaded.
[I 10:35:13.009 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /srv
[I 10:35:13.009 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 10:35:13.009 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 10:35:13.009 NotebookApp] http://[all ip addresses on your system]:8888/?token=...
[I 10:35:13.009 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[I 10:35:18.003 NotebookApp] 302 GET / (172.17.0.1) 0.50ms
[I 10:35:18.015 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree? (172.17.0.1) 0.97ms
[I 10:35:21.563 NotebookApp] 302 POST /login?next=%2Ftree%3F (172.17.0.1) 1.40ms
[I 10:35:26.118 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 10:35:26.151 NotebookApp] Writing notebook-signing key to /home/user/.local/share/jupyter/notebook_secret
[W 10:35:26.166 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:35:26.166 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:35:26.167 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1) 49.41ms referer=http://localhost:8880/tree?
[I 10:36:38.981 NotebookApp] 302 GET /tree (172.17.0.1) 1.66ms
[I 10:36:42.373 NotebookApp] 302 POST /login?next=%2Ftree (172.17.0.1) 1.12ms
[I 10:36:45.459 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 10:36:45.475 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:36:45.476 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:36:45.476 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1) 18.42ms referer=http://localhost:8880/tree
[I 10:37:19.390 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[W 10:37:19.410 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1): Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:37:19.410 NotebookApp] Permission denied: Untitled.ipynb
[W 10:37:19.411 NotebookApp] 403 POST /api/contents (172.17.0.1) 21.50ms referer=http://localhost:8880/tree
```

Answer (score 2):

First:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v $(pwd):/srv gw000/keras-full
```

The above command is to mount the current directory using "**pwd**" Linux command ("**pwd**" as in print current directory) to the folder "**/srv**" inside the container. It has nothing to do with changing the password.

<s>Secondly:</s>

It seems to me here you are using folder "**c:/Jupyter**" to mount into the container folder. You might need to run Docker as administrator or you can mount from others drive that doesn't need administrator permission like drive d:/.
So then you might try:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v d:/Jupyter:/srv gw000/keras-full
```

After seeing the **Dockerfile** at https://hub.docker.com/r/gw000/keras-full/dockerfile, I think your Docker is mounting the **/srv** as "**root**" user and the service is running under user "**user**", so you have to exec into the container by `docker exec -it <name_or_id_of_container> bash` and run `chown -R user:user /home/user /srv`

Comment: Thank you Nivhty. I'm using Windows Environment and could not run pdw. The command worked find once removed. Unfortonately, I don't have a second drive. I've tried running docker as admin without luck.

Comment: Try mounting with **c:\Jupyter**: "docker run -d -p 8888:8888 -v c:\Jupyter:/srv gw000/keras-full
"

Comment: I'm still getting Permission denied. I've tried different browsers opening normal and as admin

Comment: Can you run "**docker logs <container_name_or_id>**" to see what happened?

Comment: I've posted the details. changed port to 8880

Comment: This is the permission error inside the container. Can you mount your folder to different location than **/srv**?

Comment: I'm not sure that your service inside the container is running as root user, that might cause the problem, you need to find where the file **Untitled.ipynb** is written inside the container and change that folder's owner to the service's account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193029/discussion-between-bi-dude-and-nivhty-njgjty).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to map your local user to the docker user using `-u` e.g.

```
docker run -u $(id -u):$(id -u) ...
```